# Clickable link under overlay which is hidden on a hover selector

Tags: css

I'm looking for a **pure CSS** solution to making a link clickable under an overlay which in hidden upon hovering.

So far I've tried making the overlay opacity: 0 on hover which won't work as the overlay is still over the link, just not visible. I've also tried setting the display: none on hover which causes a flickering, I assume due to the fact that when the overlays display is set to none it removes it from the DOM so I'm not actually hovering over it any more. The closest method I tried was a combination of changing the opacity and z-index, although changing the z-index has a similar effect of setting the display to 0, creating some flickering.

Here's a simplified version of each method.

**Opacity:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Hover over me
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is my content with a <a href="#">link</a> that I want to click
  </div>
</div>
```

**Display:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.overlay:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Hover over me
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is my content with a <a href="#">link</a> that I want to click
  </div>
</div>
```

**Opacity and z-index:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Hover over me
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is my content with a <a href="#">link</a> that I want to click
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the overlay when hovering the **parent**...simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the hover to the container :)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    Hover over me
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is my content with a <a href="#">link</a> that I want to click
  </div>
</div>
```